# I can't open folder in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to merge more excel files into one and my frist step was to open a folder with VBA. This is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetFolder() As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select folder"
    .Show
    
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "GetFolder()", "No folder was selected"
    End If
    GetFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    End With
End Function


    Public Sub Merge_files()
    On Error GoTo eh
    'Get the folder from the user'
    Dim folder As String
    folder = GetFolder()
    
    Debug.Print folder
    
    
    'Read through the files in the folder'
    Dim filename As String, data As Variant
    filename = Dir(folder & "Stevci*.xlsx")
    Do While Len(filename) > 0
        'read data from the file'
        Call ReadData(data, folder & filename)
        ' write data to the main worksheet'
        
        filename = Dir
    Loop
    Exit Sub
eh: MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

To check this code I wrote Debug.Print folder but it shows nothing.
Why I can't see the name of the folder and how to fix this?

Comment: Your function **should return the folder path**. But it depends on the way you are using it. I mean, it will not return **the opened folder**. It will return the **selected folder**. Using only one click. Do you understand what I mean? When a piece of code does not return what you want, you should comment `On Error GoTo eh`. This code line must be added/uncomment only after everything works as you need. Just in case... Maybe, something else happens and you cannot see the error.

Comment: Also, `filename = Dir` should probably be `filename = Dir()` as Dir is a function.

Comment: @Paul `filename = Dir` should work just fine: Syntax is `Dir [ (pathname, [ attributes ] ) ]`

Comment: thanks @tnavidi, hadn't realized that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and the folder is displayed as it is supposed to. The `Debug.Print` outputs to the Immediate window (press Ctrl-G in the visual basic window to show this).

Maybe you should replace it with `Msgbox(folder)` if you want it as a pop-up instead.

Comment: Msgbox(folder) is also not working...I can't see any pop-ups

Comment: Are you just running the code normally? make sure you're not in edit mode (editing a cell). The msgbox should pop up even if the folder string is empty,

Comment: Also, remove `On Error Goto eh` from your code when checking why things doesn't work, there may be other things that stop your code.

Comment: @majakralj Glad to hear that. Would appreciate if you could mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left.